# Equivalent of QWebElement and QWebElementCollection in QWebEngine

Tags: qt, qtwebengine

I want to switch to `QWebEngine` from `QWebView` to be able to use the newest Qt versions. I used [`findAllElements`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qwebframe.html#findAllElements) and so on to get the `QWebElement`s and for example [`toPlainText()`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qwebframe.html#toPlainText) to get the text of it.

I cannot find something similar in QWebEngine. Do I have to use jQuery or AngularJS with `runJavascript` now? Or is there something in C++/Qt that I can use? I really want to avoid JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent in Qt WebEngine. To access these elements, you should use JavaScript from now. It is said [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html):

> In Qt WebEngine, frame handling has been merged into the
>   QWebEnginePage class. All child frames are now considered part of the
>   content, and only accessible through JavaScript. Methods of the
>   QWebFrame class, such as load() are now available directly through the
>   QWebEnginePage itself.